# Soldier of Fortune: Payback - White screen when I run

Tags: technical-issues, soldier-fortune-payback

When I sprint in Soldier of Fortune: Payback, the screen goes white and goes back to normal after a few seconds. How can I fix this?

Here is the screen shot

> [image: Soldier of fortune: Payback - White screen problem screenshot]

Comment: I assume you've tried updating your graphics drivers? Have you tried setting minimum detail in the game and see if it works?

Comment: Yes, nothing works... It is not only my problem. Google gives many such results but no solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple solution, just Delete or Move the Gui2 folder from the game directory.
UPDATE: Just delete hud.xml file from Gui2 folder

Answer (score 1):

The **[Soldier of Fortune: Payback v1.1 Patch](http://www.gamershell.com/download_22058.shtml)** is the patch that fixed it for me. Maybe it will help you.

> Here is the promised patch that fixes the Windows Vista issues and display problems.